# volley StringRequest encode

Tags: android, android-volley

every one ,every best coder.I'm a chinese. I like use volley to do some thing.But you know ,it's response always in wrong encode when I do some StringRequest and JsonObjectRequest.Like this :枃澶т腑鏂囧ぇ涓枃澶т腑鏂�  or  ää¸­æ,ä¸­æ .
I had try so many time.But response always wrong.
Who can help me????????????????

```
private void getdata() {
    String url = "http://dongcdn.b0.upaiyun.com/newfuck.txt";
    final RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest mRequest = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
            new Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response);

                    tv.setText(response);

                }
            }, new ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    mQueue.add(mRequest);
}
```

Comment: 404 error on the page, check it

Comment: zzy :  Can you give me your Code，or How me and you whisper

Comment: I think you are perhaps got into trouble with GBK and UTF-8, you received GBK text and show it in UTF-8 , so I can give you some code to try ,but could you give the right url of your text?

Comment: Sorry,this url only available in China.I can connect to it.I have tried UTF-8,GB2312,UTF-8 whih DOM,but GBK.I will try GBK later.All in all,thank you.Happy New Year!

Comment: I'm using China Internet and I can't connect it also, check it and happy new year.